# Scroll to top with JavaScript and CSS not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I've been trying to implement a smooth scroll to top using the [this CSS-Tricks Snippet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/).

Now I have the following HTML:

```
<!-- At the top of the page -->
<p id="content_jump" class="hide">
    <a id="#top"></a>
</p>

<!-- A bunch of content -->

<!-- At the bottom of the page -->
<a rel="nofollow" href="#top" id="backtotop" title="Go to top" onclick="scrollToTop();">
    Back to Top
</a>
```

Then I have the following script:

```
function scrollToTop() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#top").offset().top
    }, 1000};
    return false;
}
```

I expect this to smoothly scroll to the top of the page over the period of 1 second.

However, when I click "Back to Top" it instantly goes to the top and the console provides me with the following error:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
>     at scrollToTop ((index):274)
>     at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM1390 :245)
> ```

Any idea on a solution to the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: you have id as #top , thats why your selector does not match

Comment: You have no element with the `id` of `top`. If you want to go to the top of the page just use `scrollTop: 0`

Comment: Thanks guys, spotted it. Typical Mondays :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's throwing that error because it can't find your element with an `id` of `top`.

Looking at your code, you have an error in your `id` name.

```
<a id="#top"></a>
```

should be

```
<a id="top"></a>
```

Comment: Ah what a rookie error, thanks for spotting that!  I'll accept soon :)

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle happens to the best of us!